# My add_custom_command does not use all arguments on first cmake configuration step but does if configuration step run a second time

Tags: cmake, cmake-custom-command

I have a problem with CMake versions 3.23.1...3.27.7 (I've used the latest available major release on each).

After the configure step is run, `cmake -S . -B b -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -G Ninja`, the build directory will lack the first (second to last) argument specified in the `add_custom_command` used to call a `COMMAND`. If I immedlaly run the same configure lines as above again, then my script will be called with both arguments specified in the CMakeLists.txt file.

Example, file `entrylevel/CMakeLists.txt`

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.23..3.25)

project(EntryLevelProject
        VERSION 0.1.0
        DESCRIPTION ""
        HOMEPAGE_URL ""
        LANGUAGES C CXX ASM
)

add_executable(foo hello.m.cpp)
target_link_libraries(foo
        PRIVATE
        special::branch
)
add_custom_command(TARGET foo
        POST_BUILD
        COMMAND
        "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/my_script.sh"
        "${SpecialFilesProject_BINARY_DIR}/mango"
        "${EntryLevelProject_BINARY_DIR}/apple"
        WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}
)
```

So in my example the script will only be called with `.../my_script.sh .../apple` and not `.../my_script.sh .../mango .../apple`.

Trying a minimal example (like the above) does not produce this error.

Also trying a structure closer the real project files like this:

```
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── entrylevel
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   ├── hello.m.cpp
│   └── my_script.sh
└── specialfiles
    ├── CMakeLists.txt
    ├── inc
    │   └── specialbranch.h
    ├── one.cpp
    └── two.cpp
```

Also does not produce the error. I've also tried to use generator `-G "Unix Makefiles"` and this gives the same result as with `-G Ninja`.

So, any ides as to what could be the cause of my problem that I can't reproduce in a simple fashon?

I should add that I'm using the `--toolchain` options with my `cmake` invocation but calling it without still has the same problem with lost argument first time `cmake` is called.

Comment: Most likely some parameter of your custom command is **empty** when you configure the project for the first time. E.g. that parameter is just a dereference of a variable `SpecialFilesProject_BINARY_DIR`, which is not set until the `project(SpecialFilesProject)` is called. But after that call the variable becomes cached, so next configuration retrieves the variable value. You could easily check the variable's value by printing it via `message()` command.

Comment: Thank you for that very good insight. By swapping two top level `add_subdirectory` calls my `SpecialFilesProject_BINARY_DIR` is now set when EntryLevelProject needs it and my problem gone. Consider posting this as an answer so I can approve it.

Comment: Sorry, I don't find useful the question in the current form. 1. It doesn't contain the code which reproduces the problem. 2. There are plenty ways to dereference an uninitialized variable, and that dereference will always lead to a "missed parameter". 3. It is very easy to debug the problem by inserting `message()` calls. Much easier than search a solution on Stack Overflow.